# Enable Extract and Display Foreign Language Content in browsers using fgetcsv

Tags: php, csv, utf-8, header, fgetcsv

> iD;English [en];Chinese [zh];German [de];Hindi [hi];Hindi (TOGO) [hi_TG];Japanese [ja]
>   Source[local].AlarmGroup[AlarmText_02].ID[1310:90];Unwinder: Accu position difference too big. Check for laminate break;拆卷器： 蓄存器位置差过大。 检查复合片材是否中断;Laminatspeicher: Zu grosse Positionsänderung - Auf Laminatriss prüfen;290;;巻出装置:  アキュムレーター位置の差が大きすぎます。 ラミネートが壊れていないか確認してください
>   Source[local].AlarmGroup[AlarmText_02].ID[1311:91];Unwinder: Accu level too small for auto splice;拆卷器： 自动拼接的蓄存器级别过小;Abwickler: Akku Füllstand zu klein für Autospleiss;291;;巻出装置:  自動紙継を行うにはアキュムレーターのレベルが小さすぎます

I am trying to fetch csv content as mentioned above :

The csv file is saved as Unicode Text. It has Chinese, German, Japanese Language.
I am unable to fetch foreign language in correct format.

### CSV reader Code

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$row = 1;
$up_file = 'text_SHOT_S.csv';
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8');
if (($handle = fopen($up_file, "r")) !== FALSE) {   
     while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
           echo $data[$c].'<br>';
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);}
```

### Output of the following Code:

> iD戼㹲䔀渀最氀椀猀栀 嬀攀渀崀㰀牢>Chinese [zh]戼㹲䜀攀爀洀愀渀 嬀搀攀崀㰀牢>Hindi [hi]戼㹲䠀椀渀搀椀 ⠀吀伀䜀伀⤀ 嬀栀椀开吀䜀崀㰀牢>Japanese [ja] 戼㹲匀漀甀爀挀攀嬀氀漀挀愀氀崀⸀䄀氀愀爀洀䜀爀漀甀瀀嬀䄀氀愀爀洀吀攀砀琀开　㈀崀⸀䤀䐀嬀㄀㌀㄀　㨀㤀　崀㰀牢>Unwinder: Accu position difference too big. Check for laminate break戼㹲였睢桓ᩖ⃿쐀墄桛䵖湏읝➏ə‰쀀൧࡙䝔偲⽧♦ⵔ굎㱥牢>Laminatspeicher: Zu grosse Positionsänderung - Auf Laminatriss prüfen戼㹲㈀㤀　㰀牢>戼㹲ﬀ艹앑溈㩿  ꈀ괰ﰰ뼰ﰰ䴰湏湿䱝✰䵙夰丰縰夰Ȱ‰�촰ﰰ젰䰰쨰豘昰䐰樰䐰䬰먰赸垊昰估怰唰䐰ര㰀牢>Source[local].AlarmGroup[AlarmText_02].ID[1311:91]戼㹲唀渀眀椀渀搀攀爀㨀 䄀挀挀甀 氀攀瘀攀氀 琀漀漀 猀洀愀氀氀 昀漀爀 愀甀琀漀 猀瀀氀椀挀攀㰀牢>拆卷器： 自动拼接的蓄存器级别过小戼㹲䄀戀眀椀挀欀氀攀爀㨀 䄀欀欀甀 䘀ﰀ氀氀猀琀愀渀搀 稀甀 欀氀攀椀渀 昀ﰀ爀 䄀甀琀漀猀瀀氀攀椀猀猀㰀牢>291戼㹲㰀牢>巻出装置: 自動紙継を行うにはアキュムレーターのレベルが小さすぎます 戼㹲㰀牢

I either check garbage character or most of the content converted to Chinese.
Also tried the `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1')` and `setlocale(LC_CTYPE, 'zh_CN.UTF-8','zh_ZH.big5');`

I want the output same as CSV content.

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Do you try with utf8_en|decode function ?

Comment: Yes I did tried that its not working still.

Comment: I have try with open office calc for make the CSV and copy/past your code and I have not problem... How do you create the csv ? Try with open office calc : excel doesnt write/read in utf8 correctly

Comment: I have to make tool for this particular type of csv file which as type as Unicode text. Kindly download the file from  the link  : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8QBANjYNXmKQmM4eWRiYS04VFU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You are not in UTF-8 but in UTF-16 with BOM (I'hve check with tortoise comparator file). I try something and I come back

Comment: Can you try with this file please? 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B448oQx8BgdLNkl2UGw5UVVrVnc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I open your file in MS Excel but it doesnt seems like a Chinese language i.e. `;æ‹†å·å™¨ï¼š è“„å­˜å™¨ä½ç½®å·®è¿‡å¤§ã€` but content extraction Works!! How can i extract the same content from my file.

Comment: I've said before : MS Excel don't understand the unicode/utf-x. It's shit soft.
I've just open your doc with specifie unicode charset and copy/past the data in new doc. After, I've save the new doc in CSV and specifie UTF-8 charset. 
I'm happy if it's work for you :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reading CSV content I used PHPExcel and converted UTF-16 file into UTF-8 then it will fetch Chinese content properly.

Please refer below link for converting UTF-16 File to an UTF-8.

[How to Convert an UTF-16 File to an UTF-8 file using PHP](http://www.craiglotter.co.za/2010/03/07/how-to-convert-an-utf-16-file-to-an-utf-8-file-using-php/)

> To convert a file simply call the `convert_file_to_utf8()` function
>   and pass to it the file path of the file you wish to convert. The
>   function then uses the PHP function `file_get_contents()` to pack the
>   input file’s contents into a string variable which is then passed to
>   the main converter function which converts the string from UTF-16 to
>   UTF-8 encoding if necessary. Finally, it uses `file_put_contents()` to
>   stuff the resulting string back into the original file, overwriting
>   the original file contents.

```
function utf16_to_utf8($str) {

    $c0 = ord($str[0]);
    $c1 = ord($str[1]);

    if ($c0 == 0xFE && $c1 == 0xFF) {
        $be = true;
    } else if ($c0 == 0xFF && $c1 == 0xFE) {
        $be = false;
    } else {
        return $str;
    }

    $str = substr($str, 2);
    $len = strlen($str);
    $dec = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i += 2) {
        $c = ($be) ? ord($str[$i]) << 8 | ord($str[$i + 1]) :
                ord($str[$i + 1]) << 8 | ord($str[$i]);
        if ($c >= 0x0001 && $c <= 0x007F) {
            $dec .= chr($c);
        } else if ($c > 0x07FF) {
            $dec .= chr(0xE0 | (($c >> 12) & 0x0F));
            $dec .= chr(0x80 | (($c >> 6) & 0x3F));
            $dec .= chr(0x80 | (($c >> 0) & 0x3F));
        } else {
            $dec .= chr(0xC0 | (($c >> 6) & 0x1F));
            $dec .= chr(0x80 | (($c >> 0) & 0x3F));
        }
    }
    return $dec;
}

function convert_file_to_utf8($csvfile) {

    $utfcheck = file_get_contents($csvfile);
    $utfcheck = utf16_to_utf8($utfcheck);
    file_put_contents($csvfile, $utfcheck);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Shrikant I was able to display the the content exactly as csv. And Yes it converted the csv to utf-8 from further operation. But this works fine for me.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that :)

Answer (score 1):

Please before read this answer, read the different coment.

Mudassir, you can see the exact charset with tortoise, with comparator of file (see img) [image]

Your soft use not utf-8 but utf-16 encoding. If you cant change this, you can use http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php
http://php.net/manual/fr/mbstring.supported-encodings.php

I've try with your file and this function, and it's work correctly. See the code :

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$row = 1;
$up_file = 'text_SHOT_S.csv';
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8');
if (($handle = fopen($up_file, "r")) !== FALSE) {   
     while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
           // echo $data[$c].'<br>';
           echo mb_convert_encoding($data[$c],'utf8','utf-16').'<br>';
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);}
```

Comment: I got the content in Chinese and Japanese but the contents are not matching exactly i.e. actual content : `巻出装置: 自動紙継を行うにはアキュムレーターのレベルが小さすぎます` and extracted content : `û巺凅衮缺 ê臕则継綒が衆にはアキュムレーターのレベルが』展すぎます」` It has some `û ê` extra character

Comment: I'm sorry but it's a little bit too complicate for me ... I've search and found this, hope it's help you. When you find the solution, please come here and tell me :)
Your document is not realy in UTF-16 but in UTF-16LE (look at the screen in my answer). Check this link : http://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#gen7 
And you can try to find the good encoding with this link : http://php.net/manual/fr/mbstring.supported-encodings.php (it's for the 3th argument for mb_convert_encoding)
Good luck :)